# Custom directive using ion-view inside is not updating nav bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

As, I was refactoring my code, I saw that I had some html templates (more or less same) at different views. So I tried making a custom directive so that I could avoid duplication. But then I saw ion-view, ion-content wasn't behaving same as usual.

I have setup a plnker here :- https://plnkr.co/edit/ArcLKhsJrwDlJuNxpxYA?p=preview
This plnkr has two buttons for each tab with different Id. First button (uses my-view directive) won't update navbar (ie. showing back button and changing header) but second button does. Please let me know the correct way to correct my directive and markup.

I tried to get to the reason of why it isn't working and have a feeling that ion-view inside a my-view directive don't have direct access to its Required parent (as the doc says) ie. ion-nav-view. But I guess - there could be a workaround, if you experts could tell me.

Edit:- 
As Blue button tabs don't have back button when you try plnkr. You can use alt + left arrow keys to get back to home.

Backlinking - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-directive-using-ion-view-inside-is-not-updating-nav-bar/86727

Thanks in advance.

```js
(function (angular) {
    
    angular
        .module("testApp", ["ionic"])
        .config(Routes)
        .directive("myView", MyView)
        .controller("TabCtrl", TabCtrl)
        
    Routes.$inject = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$ionicConfigProvider"]
    
    function Routes(StateProvider, UrlRouterProvider, IonicConfigProvider) {
        // Enabling Native Scroll
        IonicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false)
        
        var states = {
            "home": {
                name: "home",
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            },
            "tab": {
                name: "tab",
                url: "/tab/:id",
                template: '<my-view tab-id="vm.id" ></my-view>',
                controller: "TabCtrl as vm"
            },
            "tab2": {
                name: "tab2",
                url: "/tab2/:id",
                templateUrl: 'templates/myView.html',
                controller: "TabCtrl as vm"
            }
        }
        
        // Registering states
        var state
        for (state in states) {
            StateProvider.state(states[state])
        }
        
        UrlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")
    }
    
    TabCtrl.$inject = ["$state", "$stateParams"]
    function TabCtrl(State, StateParams) {
        var vm = this
        vm.id = StateParams.id
    }
    
    MyView.$inject = []
    function MyView() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                id: "=tabId"
            },
            controller: ["$scope", "$timeout", MyViewCtrl],
            controllerAs: "vm",
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/myView.html"
        }
        
        function MyViewCtrl(Scope, Timeout) {
            var vm = this
            console.log(Scope)
            // Making sure controller as an impact on view
            vm.loading = true
            Timeout(function () {
                vm.loading = false
            }, 500)
        }
        
    }
    
})(angular)
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

div.spinner {
   text-align: center !important;
   position: absolute !important;
   top: 50% !important;
   left: 50% !important;
}

div.spinner ion-spinner {
   position: relative !important;
   top: -50% !important;
   left: -50% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
   <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
   <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="testApp">
     <!-- nav-bar -->
     <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-bar>
  
     <!-- nav-view -->
     <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="ng/template">
    <div id="home">
    <ion-view view-title="home">
        
        <ion-content class="padding has-header">
            
            <div class="list">
                <div class="item"
                     ng-repeat="id in [1,2,3,4,5] track by $index">
                    <button class="button button-positive" ui-sref="tab({id: id})">TabType1 - {{id}}</button>
                    <button class="button button-assertive" ui-sref="tab2({id: id})">TabType2 - {{id}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </ion-content> 
        
    </ion-view>
</div>
  </script>
  
  <script id="templates/myView.html" type="ng/template">
    <div>
    
    <ion-view view-title="{{vm.id}}">
        
        <div class="spinner" ng-if="vm.loading">
            <ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>
        </div>
        
        <ion-content class="padding has-header">
            
            <h3 ng-show="!vm.loading">
                Tab :- {{vm.id}}    
            </h3>
            
        </ion-content>
        
    </ion-view>
    
</div>
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it angular2?

Comment: No, its ionic 1 with angular 1. So Javascript, no typescript. Please check the plnkr. let me know if its not working.